# Let $G$ be a group of order $27.$ If $G$ is not abelian, then $|Z(G)|=3,$ where $Z(G) = \{z \in G: zg=gz, \forall g \in G\}$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, proof-verification

Claim: Let $G$ be a group of order $27.$ If $G$ is not abelian, then $|Z(G)|=3,$ where $Z(G) = \{z \in G: zg=gz, \forall g \in G\}$

May I know if my proof is correct? Thank you.

Lemma: $G/Z(G) $ is cyclic $\implies$  $G$ is  abelian.

Pf: Let $G/Z(G) = \left \langle {kZ(G)}\right \rangle,$ for some $k \in G.$
Given any $g_1Z(G),g_2Z(G) \in G/Z(G), \ g_1=k^nr_1$ and $g_2=k^mr_2,$ for some $n,m \in \mathbb{Z}$ and some $r_1,r_2 \in Z(G). $ It follows that $g_1g_2 = g_2g_1.$

By Lagrange's theorem $, \ |Z(G)| = 1,3,9 \ or \ 27.$

$|Z(G)| =27 \implies Z(G)=G \implies  G$ is abelian(Contradiction).

$|Z(G)|=9  \implies |G/Z(G)| =3 \implies G/Z(G)$  is  cyclic $\implies \ G$ is abelian (Contradiction)

Again, by Lagrange's theorem$, o(g) \neq 2, \forall g \in G. $

$|Z(G)|=1  \implies |G/Z(G)|=27 \implies \forall g \in G: gZ(G) \neq g^{-1}Z(G) \implies gg^{-1} =e \not \in Z(G)$. (Contradiction)

Comment: I don't understand the last step.

Comment: In the last step, $|G/Z(G)| = |\{g_iZ(G): i = 0,1,...,26.\}|=27,$ where $G = \{g_0,...,g_{26}\}.$ This means $g_iZ(G) \neq g_i^{-1}Z(G), \forall i$ (since it is impossible that $g_i^{-1}=g_i.)$

Comment: I've used this theorem in the last step: $ \forall H \leq G \ \forall g_1,g_2 \in H: g_1H=g_2H \Longleftrightarrow g^{-1}_1g_2 \in H.$

Answer (score 1):

Use the following Lemmas:

- If $G/Z(G)$ is cyclic, then $G$ is abelian.
- If $G$ is a nontrivial $p$-group, then $Z(G) \neq \{1\}$.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. See my amendments.

Answer (score 0):

In any $p - $ group $G$ whose order is say $p^n$, we cannot have the centre of $G$ is of order $p^{n-1}$. To prove this, note that

1) If $ a \in G - Z(G)$ implies $N(a) \ne G$  and hence  $N(a)$ is a proper subgroup of $G$ containing $Z(G)$ properly.

2) but there cannot be subgroup which properly contains $Z(G)$ and properly contained in $G$ in the case which we are dealing with.

Comment: Thank you, may I know how is $N(a)$ related to $a?$

Comment: $N(a)$ is the normalizer of $a$ in $G$. set of all elements of $G$ commuting with $a$.